# Haproxy load balancer with ACL

Tags: haproxy

How can we configure Haproxy as a Cookie based Load-Balacer depending upon the cookies status? i.e. if the cookie is absent then redirect to server1 & if cookies is present then server2?

I search for this then i get ACL but it's for Header, can we configure it for cookies presence?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I examine the value of the cookie "fslanguage" and set the Accept-Language header in the request based on the language.   You could easily do a backend rule (see use_backend) instead of a reqrep rule.

```
    acl langCookie_en cook(fslanguage) en
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ en,\1 if langCookie_en
    acl langCookie_fr cook(fslanguage) fr
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ fr,\1 if langCookie_fr
    acl langCookie_de cook(fslanguage) de
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ de,\1 if langCookie_de
    acl langCookie_es cook(fslanguage) es
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ es,\1 if langCookie_es
    acl langCookie_pt cook(fslanguage) pt
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ pt,\1 if langCookie_pt
    acl langCookie_it cook(fslanguage) it
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ it,\1 if langCookie_it
    acl langCookie_ru cook(fslanguage) ru
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ ru,\1 if langCookie_ru
    acl langCookie_ja cook(fslanguage) ja
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ ja,\1 if langCookie_ja
    acl langCookie_ko cook(fslanguage) ko
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ ko,\1 if langCookie_ko
    acl langCookie_zh cook(fslanguage) zh
      reqrep Accept-Language:\ (.*) Accept-Language:\ zh,\1 if langCookie_zh
```